# Simpliest way to convert array of Integer to array of String in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to convert an `Integer[]` but `toArray()` is giving me `Object[]`. How can I convert it to `String[]`?

```
Stream.of(ids).map(String::valueOf).toArray();
```

Comment: Is it an `int[]` or an `Integer[]`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Integer[]

Comment: Not really a duplicate of the other question.  This involves array of Integer[], which is a special case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String[] array = Stream.of(ids).map(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I am surprise, Is this a method reference? New keyword can be treat as method?

Comment: @richersoon It's a reference to the constructor

Comment: method references can be used for constructors as well as methods

Comment: When you have an existing array, it’s recommended to use `Arrays.stream` instead. This will consistently work for `int[]`, `long[]` and `double[]` as well (you only have to use `mapToObj` instead of `map` then), whereas `Stream.of` only works for boxed values and it’s intended use case is the varargs invocation like `Stream.of(a, b, c)`…

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] a= Arrays.toString(array).split("[\\[\\]]")[1].split(", ");
```

I think this should work